# Automate process for creating environment

Tags: java, maven, environment

I heard of puppet and chef for creating the environment on the fly. But that is on big level.

I was thinking whenever a programmer gets new machine he has to install java, maven etc which are basic tools to start with for any Java/J2EE programmer. And for version of each tools- either it's latest version or as per project structure.
Is there any way to automate this file. Just like a bash file (on windows) or something which can install all these basic tools with desired version. Any hint to start with will be great.

Thank you.

Comment: There is a tool named "hand" :p (More seriously an option is to use some kind of custom OS install)

Comment: just write a batch file or use powershell or something